# [Unity][Photon] Syncing players connected with new players connecting

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have a stats script defining a player like its MaximumHealth, its name etc. Every player has a List of those scripts locally. When a player connects I want him to complete his List asking through RPCs

I tried to `photonView.RPC("AskInfos", PhotonTargets.MasterClient, photonView.viewID);` on the connecting player to the master client in order to get him send me the infos I need

```c#
[PunRPC]
public void AskInfos(int id)
{
    PhotonView pv = PhotonView.Find(id);
    string[] toSend = new string[stats.players.Count];

    for(int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
    {
        toSend[i] = JsonUtility.ToJson(players[i]);
    }

    photonView.RPC("ReceiveInfos", pv.owner, toSend, team, id);
}
```

Then the master client calls `ReceiveInfos`on the connecting player with the list of his players he actually knows

```c#
[PunRPC]
void ReceiveInfos(string[] plyrs, int teamNumber, int id)
{
    List<playerStatsSerializable> playersSentList = new List<playerStatsSerializable>();

    for (int i = 0; i < plyrs.Length; i++)
    {
        playersSentList.Add(JsonUtility.FromJson<playerStatsSerializable>(plyrs[i]));
    }

    players = playersSentList;

    //stats is actually a playerStatsSerializable

    stats.teamNumber = teamNumber;
    stats.uniqueID = id;
    stats.username = PhotonNetwork.player.NickName;

    string toSend = JsonUtility.ToJson(stats);

    photonView.RPC("AddPlayer", PhotonTargets.All, toSend);
}
```

Then the connecting player calls AddPlayer to add him to the local list of every other player including him (because the `playersSentList`is not including him)

```c#
[PunRPC]
void AddPlayer(string st)
{
    players.Add(JsonUtility.FromJson<playerStatsSerializable>(st));
} //players is the local list containing all the players in the room
```

Once I connect two players in the same room each only has his player in his list, the host has one player "host" and the client one player "client"

I don't know if this is clear enough I tried my best
If someone knows an easier way to sync a List when a player joins I would appreciate 
Thanks in advance

Edit : When I set the targets of all rpcs here to All only clients have the right List but the host is stuck with only one player "host" wth.
But only names are correct ids are all the same :///

Comment: Have you added any debugging to see if your scripts are actually executing? Seems like you could log a lot of information in each of them to determine what, if anything, is being sent and probably figure out what's missing.

Comment: Yeah i actually did but i removed them to post it, i'll do a bit of debug to inform you

Comment: @RetiredNinja see edit but I dont understand at all